# Power supply for 9.4 GHz magnetron

Tags: power-supply, circuit-design, magnetron

I need a power supplier for a magnetron with following specifications.
Can someone help me out with the design?

- Frequency 9380 to 9440 MHz (Fixed)
- Output power (Peak)   25 kW
- Duty cycle / Pulse duration   0.001 / 1.2 μsec
- Anode voltage (Peak)  8 kV
- Anode current (Peak)  8 A
- Heater voltage    6.3 V (@ Preheat)
- Heater current    0.52 A

Comment: OP can find the MIT Radiation Lab Series on line (https://archive.org/details/mit-rad-lab-series-version-2/VOL_1_Radar_System_Engineering/). A wealth of information about this sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

A general scheme could be as follows:
[image]
Leafing through the text published at the beginning of the last century: "Introduction to Radar Systems" by SKOLNIK - Publisher McGraw - Hill, I found this page that may interest you:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a switch such as a thyratron or solid-state equivalent, a transformer and a pulse-forming network.

[image]

A paper showing the detailed design of the pulse-forming network (from which the images above and below were taken) can be found [here](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265009076_Design_of_an_Pulse-Forming_Network_for_Driving_High_Power_Magnetron).

***Design of an Pulse-Forming Network for Driving High Power Magnetron***
Nivaldo Carleto & C R B Miranda

This circuit produces 9kV pulses of 700ns duration and 2kHz frequency to a 31Ω load,
which is rather close to the requirements of your magnetron.

[image]